# Remove pre heades from csv before using DictReader - Python

Tags: python, csv, parsing

Hi I have csv file like this

```
here is some text
some more text
summary
id score
1   33
2   22
3   11
detail 
id try score
1  1    22
1  2    11
2  1    10
2  2    12
3  1    11
```

I want to parse the data id, try, score which comes after detail to DictReader
How can I do that?

Comment: This is not a proper csv file.

Comment: This is a sample file. This is how my file looks like.  I need to remove all the lines before "id try score" for further steps. How can i do that?

Comment: Can you parse for any line starting with a numeric and only process those?

Comment: Hi it worked. 

n = 0
    for line in csvfile.readlines():
        n += 1
        if 'detail' in line: # line with field names was found
            h = line.split(',')
            break
    #csvfile.close()
    csvfile = islice(open("test.csv", "r"), n, None)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this :

```
import csv

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

relevant_lines = text.split('detail \n')[1].splitlines()

d_reader = csv.DictReader(relevant_lines, delimiter= ' ', skipinitialspace=True)

print(d_reader.fieldnames)

for row in d_reader:
    print(row)
```

This outputs :

```
['id', 'try', 'score']
{'score': '22', 'try': '1', 'id': '1'}
{'score': '11', 'try': '2', 'id': '1'}
{'score': '10', 'try': '1', 'id': '2'}
{'score': '12', 'try': '2', 'id': '2'}
{'score': '11', 'try': '1', 'id': '3'}
```

I basically filtered out everything before the line containing 'detail' (this line included), and then parsed it as a csv file.

I used `skipinitialspace=True` to make sure consecutive whitespaces are only interpreted as one delimiter.